# Nvd3.js lineChartWithFocus all markers and values

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

is there a way to use nvd3.js with lineChartWithFocus such as on 
[github example](https://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/lineWithFocusChart.html)

and to have each value dotted (i actually managed to do this with CSS) but also next to it value. So in this link above there would be 70 
[image: picture]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you upload an annotated screenshot showing what you want?

Comment: @jeznag there you go - i edited post

Comment: @Krešimir Fijačko What exactly you want? unable to get your question.

Comment: i want those dots and values next to it on every measurement